# Ember Query Parameter cant send value in hash

Tags: ember.js

I cant send the query param value to call set pageno value

template code :

```
{{#each @model.PageNo as |item|}}
  <LinkTo @route="getServices" @query={{hash pageno="{{item.pgno}}" }} >{{item.pgno}}</LinkTo>
{{/each}}
```

controller :

```js
export default class GetServicesController extends Controller {
  queryParams = ['pageno'];

  @tracked pageno = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{#each @model.PageNo as |item|}}
  <LinkTo @route="getServices" @query={{hash pageno=item.pgno}} >{{item.pgno}}</LinkTo>
{{/each}}
```

this should work